# Filtering with Linux command line

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I want to filter some dataset like this

```
1    26
1    32
2    45
2    56
3    26
.
.
1000  33
```

All fields that have column=1 have to be exported to a csv file, and with column=2, and etc. The code I have is this:

```
for i in {0..1000}
do
    awk '$1=="$i" {print $1,$2} ' Gowalla_edges.txt > file{$i}.csv
done
```

but just creates empty csv files.  What's wrong — how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that the shell doesn't expand `$i` because it is inside single quotes in:

```
awk '$1=="$i" {print $1,$2} ' Gowalla_edges.txt > file{$i}.csv
```

You should probably use the `-v` option to pass a shell variable to `awk`:

```
awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i {print $1,$2}' Gowalla_edges.txt > file{$i}.csv
```

The simplest change would be this (with two extra single quotes adjacent to `"$i"`):

```
awk '$1=='"$i"' {print $1,$2}' Gowalla_edges.txt > file{$i}.csv
```

Both of these would work.

However, your overall process would be somewhat slow as it makes 1000 passes over the source data.  That's perhaps OK if you're only dealing with a few thousand lines in total, but it is otherwise too slow (for millions of lines).

Is the data in sorted order?  It would be more efficient if it is sorted, though this script should work even if it isn't (it will just open some output files more than once).  You should be able to use a single pass over the data, like this:

```
awk '$1 != old { if (file) close(file)
                 file = "file" $1 ".csv"; old = $1 }
               { print $0 >> file }' Gowalla_edges.txt
```

On your sample data, it generates:

```
$ ls -l file*.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  10 May  5 17:28 file1.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   8 May  5 17:28 file1000.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  10 May  5 17:28 file2.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   5 May  5 17:28 file3.csv
$ cat file2.csv
2 45
2 56
$
```

Comment: You don't need the `if (file)` as `close(file)` will do nothing if file is null. You also don't need the $0 in `print $0`.

Comment: Thanks, the first code works. It is sorted. Thanks a lot